# TFS 2017 not displaying "Remaining Work" in backlog

Tags: tfs

Our Setup: 
1: Using TFS 2017
2: Using Agile process templates

In our web portal for our TFS backlog, we're unable to display the values of the "Remaining Work" field - the field is displaying as a column option, but none of the values are showing.
[Backlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GURRn.png)

However when you create a custom query the data is there. We've checked that we're using the correct column header that is specified in the Work Item Type. 
[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRynJ.png)

Does anyone know why this wouldn't be appearing when selecting the backlog?

Answer (score 2):

User Stories/PBIs don't **have** a *Remaining Work* field by default. What you're seeing in the backlog view is the sum of the values of the *Remaining Work* fields on any child work items.

If someone went and modified the process template and put the *Remaining Work* field on your user stories, that would explain what you're seeing. You're filling in a field on your User Story, so it appears in the query view. But in the backlog view, it's summing up all of the remaining work on the child Tasks, of which there appear to be none, so you get no value there.